# How to restore a model in distributed tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, distributed

I have trained the model using 4 CPU machines.For restoring it do I need to save the model on every machine? And how do I get the saved state from each CPU on the chief node so that it can be restored?
Currently, if I try to restore the model error I am facing is

> tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful
>   TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for
>   ./newsvr.ckpt